# Android : how to ignore an xml element below a defined Android SDK version?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I have in my xml an element from a third party library. Let say that it is a specific button named "SuperButton":

```
<com.library.SuperButton
  android:id="@+id/my_super_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

My project should run on Android 2.1 but my SuperButton is only designed for Android 2.2 and higher (Froyo). What should I add in my xml to make sure that the SuperButton will be ignored (and consequently not displayed ; and will not crash the app...) on Android 2.1 ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create two layout files.
Put the 2.1 version in the /res/layout/ folder and the 2.2+ version in the /res/layout-v8/ folder.

Now everything with API level 8 or higher (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) will take the xml from the layout-v8 folder. Everything else from the default folder.